# IBM Cloud object storage: What is value of aws_access_key_id?

Tags: ibm-cloud, object-storage

Here are the fields in service credential (values anonymized) for IBM Cloud object storage service. What field maps to aws_access_key_id for using S3 APIs? Unfortunately I wasn't able to find this mapping anywhere in docs!!! Really sad

{
  "apikey": "anonymized",
  "endpoints": "https://cos-service.bluemix.net/endpoints",
  "iam_apikey_description": "Auto generated apikey during resource-key operation for Instance - crn:v1:bluemix:public:cloud-object-storage:global:a/anonymized",
  "iam_apikey_name": "auto-generated-apikeyanonymized",
  "iam_role_crn": "crn:v1:bluemix:public:iam::::serviceRole:Writer",
  "iam_serviceid_crn": "crn:v1:bluemix:public:iam-identity::a/anonymized",
  "resource_instance_id": "crn:v1:bluemix:public:cloud-object-storage:global:a/anonymized"
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See here to generate HMAC (S3 style credentials)
https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/cloud-object-storage/iam/service-credentials.html#service-credentials

After the Service Credential is created, the HMAC Key is included in the cos_hmac_keys field